# Manifest file not being generated through ANT

Tags: java, eclipse, ant

Manifest file not being generated through ANT. From what it looks like, an oata.HelloWorld should be generated and I am assuming it is the Manifest File. However, it is not in the build/class folder or the build/jar folder. I am also running ANT through eclipse

```
Buildfile: C:\Users\dt208672\Perforce\depot\ebill\Automation\Selenium_eBill\MarketPower\build.xml
init:
prepare:
compile:
[javac] C:\Users\dt208672\Perforce\depot\ebill\Automation\Selenium_eBill\MarketPower\build.xml:18: warning: 'includeantruntime' was not set, defaulting to build.sysclasspath=last; set to false for repeatable builds
jar:
run:
[java] Error: Could not find or load main class oata.HelloWorld
[java] Java Result: 1
```

This is my xml code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>

<project name="SeleniumProjectDataDriven" basedir="." default="run">
<target name="init">
    <property name="src.dir" value="src" />
    <property name="build.dir" value="build" />
    <property name="classes.dir" value="${build.dir}/class" />
    <property name="lib.dir" value="../JAR/MarketPower Jars" />
    <property name="Common.dir" value="../Common" />
    <property name="CommonBin.dir" value="${Common.dir}/bin" />
</target>

<target name="prepare" depends="init">
    <mkdir dir="${classes.dir}" />
</target>

<target name="compile" description="Compiles the code" depends="prepare">
    <javac srcdir="${src.dir}" destdir="${classes.dir}">
        <classpath>
            <fileset dir="${lib.dir}">
                <include name="**/*.jar" />
            </fileset>
        </classpath>
    </javac>
</target>

<target name="jar" description="Packages the code into jar" depends="compile">
    <mkdir dir="build/jar"/>
        <jar destfile="build/jar/HelloWorld.jar" basedir="build/class">
            <manifest>
                <attribute name="Main-Class" value="oata.HelloWorld"/>
            </manifest>
        </jar>
</target>

<target name="run" description="Run the jar file" depends="jar" >
    <java jar="build/jar/HelloWorld.jar" fork="true"/>
</target>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is the exact opposite of what you say. The Jar file has **only** the manifest, as indicated by the error message that knows the name of the main class `oata.HelloWorld`.

You need to add the compiled .class files to the Jar file.

```
<jar destfile="build/jar/HelloWorld.jar">
    <manifest>
        <attribute name="Main-Class" value="oata.HelloWorld"/>
    </manifest>
    <fileset dir="${classes.dir}" includes="**/*.class"/>
</jar>
```

**Updated**

The following works fine for me.

*src\oata\HelloWorld.java*:

```
package oata;
public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World");
    }
}
```

*build.xml*:

```
<project name="SeleniumProjectDataDriven" basedir="." default="run">
  <target name="init">
    <property name="src.dir" value="src" />
    <property name="build.dir" value="build" />
    <property name="classes.dir" value="${build.dir}/class" />
    <property name="jar.dir" value="${build.dir}/jar" />
  </target>

  <target name="compile" description="Compiles the code" depends="init">
    <mkdir dir="${classes.dir}" />
    <javac srcdir="${src.dir}" destdir="${classes.dir}" includeantruntime="false" />
  </target>

  <target name="jar" description="Packages the code into jar" depends="compile">
    <mkdir dir="${jar.dir}" />
    <jar destfile="${jar.dir}/HelloWorld.jar" basedir="build/class">
      <manifest>
        <attribute name="Main-Class" value="oata.HelloWorld" />
      </manifest>
    </jar>
  </target>

  <target name="run" description="Run the jar file" depends="jar" >
    <java jar="${jar.dir}/HelloWorld.jar" fork="true" />
  </target>
</project>
```

*Output*:

```
compile:
Compiling 1 source file to C:\My\Workspaces\EMDRS\_test\build\class

jar:
Building jar: C:\My\Workspaces\EMDRS\_test\build\jar\HelloWorld.jar

run:
Hello World

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 1 second
```

Comment: If you open the .jar file, e.g. rename to .zip and open with WinZip, does it contain a file named `oata/HelloWorld.class`?